# Possible causes of org.springframework.mail.MailSendException / java.net.ConnectException?

Tags: java, spring, email, cloud-foundry

I have a Spring Boot application which once a day should send some emails to users that needs to be informed about some specific events from that day. I'm using `spring-boot-starter-mail` dependency and `JavaMailSender` provided by it.

My application.proiperties config for mails looks like this (with proper host, user and password data ofcourse):

```
spring.mail.host = myhost.com
spring.mail.username = user@myhost.com
spring.mail.password = mypassword
spring.mail.port = 25
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
```

and code responsible for sending mails is:

```
private void sendMessage(String email, String text, String subject) {
    try {
        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);

        helper.setFrom(SENDER);
        helper.setSubject(subject);
        helper.setTo(email);
        helper.setText(text, true);

        javaMailSender.send(message);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MailException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

where `javaMailSender` is autowired and SENDER is always set to value of `spring.mail.username` property. This method is called in a loop within scheduled job, usually about 10 to 20 times (for each email that should be notified).

It works with no problem when I run this on my local machine or company server, but when the application is running on pivotal cloud foundry, it sends 2 or 3 first emails and then throws

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: myhost.com, 25; timeout -1;
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: myhost.com, 25; timeout -1;
...
```

**What can be possible cause of this?** I tried to find answer but every described problem which I could find was about mails not working at all, usually due to bad configuration and this is not the case (I think) as I can successfuly send emails from two different machines (both of them outside of mailing host local network) but can't from pivotal cloud (or to be more specific - can do it only partially before exception arise).